# put string as javascript object

Tags: javascript, escaping

i've the following object and I need to put the "string",how should I put the value of name

**{"name":{"_parent":["/test"]}}**

inside,I try with " which doesnt work for me ,any idea ?

```
var file = {
   "name" : "{"name":{"_parent":["/test"]}}"
```

**update**
 I cannot use the jsonParse or stringify as I need to put it hardcoded

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: Parsing goes from string to JS, folks. `file` is an object, not a string.

Comment: Is your string will always be a safe JSON ?
With JSON safe you may use this formula 

`"name": JSON.parse({"name": {"_parent": ["/test"]}})`

Comment: @SaadShahd No, that will give a parse error, because it's not a string.

Comment: What does that mean, "you need to put it hardcoded"? What do you expect to see as the result?

Comment: This won't even parse as written, btw, because you're using double-quotes everywhere.

Comment: @DaveNewton - so how to fix the double-quats this is my questoin

Comment: Use single-quotes *and* double-quotes? You're not describing the problem or what you want very well. You didn't even include what you thought should work and didn't--but it'll work if you do it right. Whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @DaveNewton - how can you show me please

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to do, so no.

Comment: @DaveNewton - the value is coming from a file I want to put this value inside the object (name:= value),with the right escaping ...how?

Comment: @JhonDree *What specifically is coming from the file???* Are you trying to *read* a file and use that as the value?! In what JS environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but I think you want to do this
The reason why JSON.parse() is not working for you is because you are missing the single quotes.

```
var yourString = '{"_parent":["/test"]}'

var file  = '{"name" : {"name":{"_parent":["/test"]}}}'

var obj = JSON.parse(file);
obj.name.name = yourString;
var backToString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this :

```
JSON.parse(file);
```

For more information you could look in this site :

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: object -> string would be JSON.stringify